# Same code in cocos2d-x produces different graphical output. Why does this Happen and how to correct it?

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I have a project which I build on Android and Linux in cocos2d-x. In this I have a little rocket-ship which has 2 thrusters with both have its own little flame. I build the Node for it like this:

```
    //create ship node
    this->shipNode = cocos2d::Node::create(); 
    this->addChild(shipNode);
    //place it in the middle of the screen
    shipNode->setPosition(Vec2(visibleSize.width / 2 + origin.x, visibleSize.height / 2 + origin.y));
    shipNode->setScale(5);

    auto rocketSprite = loadSprite("rocket.png");
    
    Sprite* flame_0 = loadSprite("flames/flame_00.png");
    Sprite* flame_1 = loadSprite("flames/flame_00.png");

    shipNode->addChild(rocketSprite, 1);
    shipNode->addChild(flame_0, 1);
    shipNode->addChild(flame_1, 1);

    rocketSprite->setAnchorPoint(Vec2(0.5f, 0.5f));
    flame_0->setPosition(Vec2(-3.5f, -(16)));
    flame_1->setPosition(Vec2(+3.5f, -(16)));
    rocketSprite->setPosition(Vec2(0, 0));

    flame_1->setScaleX(-1); //mirroring the flame
```

This produces a graphical output like so: (On the left Linux, On the right Android)
[image: Ship]

What I Would like to know is how to get the position of the elements to be consistent without having write platform specific code. I did also try to explicitly setting the Anchor Points individually (setAnchorPoint(Vec2(0.5f, 0.5f)), aswell as setting them to be ignored (setIgnoreAnchorPointForPosition(true)). The output is never consistent across devices.

Answer (score 0):

I did end up solving the issue. The misallignment only occurs if the content scale factor is set to something other than 1. This is set by AppDelegate::applicationDidFinishLaunching in AppDelegate.cpp, which is added in to a project by default.